# Request a Laravel eloquent Structure or otherway

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c6C1.jpg)

Hello, 
I would like to ask your advice. As you see I have these tables structure. I want to get a reservation with contents. But in my structure I can't get truly data.

For order_id - 1 I get -> 
reservation id 1  res_name_1
reservation id 2 res_name_2 ( instead extra id 2 )

I hope, I explaned clearly.

Best Regards.

Murat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `Order` model and your relationships are established in it to a `Reservation` model:

```
$orderId = 1;

// Get just the reservation for the order
$reservation = Order::find($orderId)->reservation;

// Get the order and the reservation.
$reservation = Order::find($orderId)->with(['reservation'])->get();
```

Another Further assumption is your relationship in the `Order` models relationship to the `Reservation` model looks something like the following:

```
    /**
     * Get the reservation record associated with the order.
     */
    public function reservation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Reservation');
    }
```

Another assumption is you foreign a key set up in your database orders table through a migration.

```
$table->foreign('reservation_id')->references('id')->on('reservations');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#defining-models

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Your question is very vague on what you have codewise and can only be answered with unknown assumptions.